# Group millions records in one map of Hazelcast and create new map

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am looking for performance while grouping records (may be millions) in one map of hazelcast and store in other map of hazelcast.

### For Example:

In first map of hazelcast, I have records (take 10000) which is in String format (converted to string using ObjectMapper from java POJO).

Each record is related to one student but not in order i.e first record can be of student 1, 2nd record can be of student 2, 3rd record can be again of student 1 and so on.

Now I want to group all 10k records by student and store in other map of hazelcast so say 2nd map should be `Map<studenid, List<Record>>` where studentid is string and value is list of records in first map related to that student.

I have written code to group records and work good but taking much time say for 10k records it is taking 4 minutes.

**My code flow:**

1. streaming data of first map of hazelcast using JDK8 stream feature.
2. For each record, checking in 2nd map in hazelcast that any record exist or not (here List).
3. If not then create new List, put record in that list and put list in hazelcast's new map.
4. Performing all above steps for all 10k records.

Can anybody suggest better way to achieve as actual expected records are more than 300k?

Comment: Do you use the aggregation api? What version of Hazelcast?

Comment: I am using HC 3.8.3. aggregation api of JDK 8?

Comment: I dont want to load entire map say of 10000 in my local memory and then do grouping. That is why using streaming on first map but for 2nd map writing, two hazelcast call is being fired for all record. One to read data from map for student and then 2nd to write again which causes slowness.

Comment: No I mean the Hazelcast Aggregation API :) http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8/manual/html-single/index.html#fast-aggregations

Comment: No. I have not. Thanks I will look right away. Can you suggest which API is most suitable if you can think of my example so I can save some time?

Comment: The idea of the Hazelcast aggregation api is to run distributed, that said, you don't need to get all the data to your local application to calculate it. What might be ok with small datasets, will not work with big ones. Hazelcast Jet might be worth a look too.

Comment: so If I write code like this "IMap<String, SalaryYear> salaries = hazelcastInstance.getMap( "salaries" );", does not it load whole salaries map from hazelcast in my memory?

Comment: So to perform grouping as per my requirement I have to write custom code so does hazelcast aggregate function gives performance?

Comment: 1: no, this doesn't load everything into your caller but if you use the stream api, you eventually will; 2: yes you probably have to write a bit of custom code.

Comment: I think if I use stream then it will not use everything on caller but stream data one by one from hazelcast map. So based on your answer IMap is kind of streaming or what? So on IMap whether I use stream or not is there no difference?

Comment: actually I am streaming data on Map like "hazelcast.getMap(cacheName).entrySet().stream()" instead of "IMap<String, SalaryYear> salaries = hazelcastInstance.getMap( "salaries" );" and do iteration on salaries thinking 1st way give good performance as it will not load whole map at caller side.

Comment: in addition to this, get method return clone of data of map so confused that how "IMap<String, SalaryYear> salaries = hazelcastInstance.getMap( "salaries" );" would not load everyghin in to caller.

Comment: It does not stream data, `IMap::entries` will retrieve all values into the local JVM and create a standard Java 8 stream from it. What makes you think it'll actually stream elements? A name coming from "some" API which was created after the Hazelcast IMap? ;)

Comment: ok got it. So what is the way to operate on hazelcast data without loading in local JVM? merely using IMap will work like that? So how can I improve performance of my actual requirement?

Comment: See comment above: Hazelcast Jet or Hazelcast Aggregations API

Comment: Thanks.... I will surely look in to both. Still one thought roaming around mind. if use Aggregation API then it would not load all data in JVM, then where aggregation API performs operation? In hazelcast memory area or where?

Comment: As a distributed operation, it will execute colocated to the data, so inside the cluster on all the nodes.

Comment: Okk thanks noctarius.... will start work on aggregation API. Thanks for help. I will connect again if any query.

Comment: So if I have only one node in cluster then even it will do right?

Comment: yes, however there's nothing meaningful like a "one-node-cluster"

Comment: ok... if I dont have to use any aggregation just want to read records from one map of hazelcast having millions of records. So if I do IMap obj = hazelcastInstance.getMap("refName") will not load all millions records in JVM? If I get one value using key then it will load that element in the JVM?

Comment: At final.... can you share any technical document where I get good explanation of how hazelcast works internally? I went through all available on net but did not get any which explain what happen if I use IMap whether it loads data on JVM or not? I need such kind of document if you can share.

Comment: One thing I noticed... I created IMap object like "IMap obj = instance.getMap("")" and performed obj.size() and got total number of records. So I got confused that you were saying IMap does not load all records in local JVM then how count is total number of record? Please comment on this as I need to clear my thoughts about Hazelcast working.

Comment: It is a remote operation, as explained in the documentation, if you have parallel mutations, it is an estimation as different nodes might run the local count operation at different times. The caller only retrieves intermediate size results (one per node) and sums those up. Please read the documentation.